# I am encountering multiple "error: missing return statement" errors on a couple of my methods. What have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors

I am currently trying to modify a class called Coin that implements an interface called Lockable to lock the methods until a password is entered to unlock them. When I try to compile my code I am given the following errors:

```
C:\Users\mrowl_000\Dropbox\APCS\Ch. 5\Ch. 5 Projects\Three\Coin.java:112: error: missing return statement
   }
   ^
C:\Users\mrowl_000\Dropbox\APCS\Ch. 5\Ch. 5 Projects\Three\Coin.java:137: error: missing return statement
   }
   ^
2 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Coin implements Lockable
{

   private final int HEADS = 0;
   private final int TAILS = 1;
   private int password;
   private boolean isUnlocked = true;
   private int face;

   public void setKey(int key)
    {
        password = key;
    }

    public void lock(int userKey)
    {
        int userpass = userKey;
        int accessKey = password;

        if (userpass != accessKey)
        {
            System.out.println("The following methods have been locked.");
            isUnlocked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The following methods have been unlocked.");
            isUnlocked = true;
        }
    }

    public void unlock(int userKey)
    {
        int userpass = userKey;

        if (userpass != password)
        {
            System.out.println("The following methods have been locked.");
            isUnlocked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The following methods have been unlocked.");
            isUnlocked = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean locked()
    {
        return isUnlocked;
    }

   //END LOCKABLE

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets up the coin by flipping it initially.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Coin ()
   {
      boolean result = locked();

            if (result == false)
            {
                System.out.println("The coin method is locked");
            }
            else
            {
                flip();
        }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Flips the coin by randomly choosing a face value.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void flip ()
   {
       boolean result = locked();

            if (result == false)
            {
                System.out.println("The coin method is locked");
            }
            else
            {
                face = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns true if the current face of the coin is heads.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isHeads ()
   {
      boolean result = locked();

            if (result == false)
            {
                System.out.println("The coin method is locked");
            }
            else
            {
                return (face == HEADS);
        }
   } // <---Error Here

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the current face of the coin as a string.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
   {
      boolean result = locked();

            if (result == false)
            {
                System.out.println("The coin method is locked");
            }
            else
            {
                String faceName;

                if (face == HEADS)
                   faceName = "Heads";
                else
                   faceName = "Tails";


                return faceName;
        }
   } // <---Error Here
}
```

In case it is needed, here is the interface called Lockable:

```
public interface Lockable
{
   public void setKey (int value);
   public void lock(int key);
   public void unlock(int key);
   public boolean locked();
}
```

I put comments where the errors occur. Could someone be so kind as to point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Just a small security concern: you should remove any account identifying information from things you post about your system, like that your username is `mrowl_000`.  Not *that* big of a deal, but you can never be too careful.  The more information you expose, the more vulnerable you make you and your systems. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every branch of if-else statement needs a return value. The following code will work:

```
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns true if the current face of the coin is heads.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isHeads ()
   {
      boolean result = locked();

            if (result == false)
            {
                System.out.println("The coin method is locked");

                return false; // <-- you need a return value here.
            }
            else
            {
                return (face == HEADS);
        }
   } // <---Error Here

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the current face of the coin as a string.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
   {
      boolean result = locked();

            if (result == false)
            {
                System.out.println("The coin method is locked");

                return null; // <-- you need a return value here.
            }
            else
            {
                String faceName;

                if (face == HEADS)
                   faceName = "Heads";
                else
                   faceName = "Tails";


                return faceName;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The IF blocks in both the cases are not returning anything and so the error. All code paths must return something in line with the return type, right?

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty clearly states why it appears.

You always need to reach a `return` statement in a function with a return value. Your `isHeads()` function only reaches the return statement when `isHeads==true`.

You could for example throw an Exception if the coin method is locked. Then just return `(face == HEADS)`

The same with the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you need a return statement at those lines.

If you don't want a result when the object is locked, you should probably throw an exception, like this:

```
public boolean isHeads(){
    if(!locked())
        throw new methodLockException();
    return (face == HEADS);
}
```

Also, locked should reflect what it says: it should return true if it is **locked**, not if it is unlocked, as it appears to be now.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error even though you have a return statement because it's possible to execute the method without reaching the return statement.

```
public boolean isHeads ()
   {
      boolean result = locked();

            if (result == false)
            {
                **If you enter this if condition, the return statement is never reached**
                System.out.println("The coin method is locked");
            }
            else
            {
                return (face == HEADS);
        }
   } // <---Error Here
```

You should set up your method so that it will return something in any situation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the return statement for the `toString()` and to the `isHeads ()` to remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't have a gurenteed `return` statement, for example, in the following snippet...

```
public boolean isHeads() {
    boolean result = locked();

    if (result == false) {
        System.out.println("The coin method is locked");
        return (face == HEADS);
    }
} // <---Error Here
```

The only possible return is if `result == false`...what do you return when it's `true`?

The same thing goes for your `toString` method.

Personally, I'm old school, I like one entry point and one exit point, so I might do something like...

```
public boolean isHeads() {
    boolean result = locked();

    return !result ? face == HEADS : false;
} // <---Error Here
```